# Find the geometic sequence using python

Tags: python

Using geometric difference int(8/5*n-(3/2)) to calculate the next sequential value. Then display the number grid using the values in the geometric progression. Once the grid is complete, program should display the arithmetic sum of all the values in the grid.

Example result is:

```
Number of rows: 6
Starting integer: 8 
Geometric difference: <display algorithm  here>

Your gird with 6 rows starting with 8 is:

8     11    16    24   36   56
88    139   220   350  558
891   1424  2276  3640
5822  9313  14899
23836 38136
61016
```

I did:

```
r = eval(input("number of rows:"))
i = eval(input("Starting integer:"))
g = eval(input("Geometric difference:"))

input("Your grid with"  "rows starting with" "is:")
for y in range(c):
    for x in range(r):
        print( i, ' ', end=' ')
        i += 1
    print ()
```

It is not working, where should I fix?

Comment: Please add more details about your problem?

Comment: if a response helped you solving your issue, please vote it up and mark this response as the answer to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is used to evaluate python code. You do not need it here at all. If you want to use the input as an integer you have to use `int()` (or `float()` for a float value, etc.)

Please correct your first three line to:

```
r = int(input("number of rows:"))
i = int(input("Starting integer:"))
g = int(input("Geometric difference:"))
```

`input` is used to enter a something.

```
input("Your grid with"  "rows starting with" "is:")
```

I think here you want to `print` something; therefore, you should use:

```
print("Your grid with {0} rows starting with {1} is:".Format(r, i))
```

This will at least solve the syntax errors of your code. But you should at more information about the problem you want to solve (and how one calculates the sequence) in your first post.

Edit: this will then produce your output:

```
for y in range(r):
    for x in range(r-y):
        print( i, ' ', end=' ')
        i=int(8*i/5-1.5)
    print()
```

Comment: How do you add all the integers displayed? It is spread out by row and columns.